# openshift internal docker registry repo address is no same as docker-registry service cluster ip

Tags: docker, openshift

My steps in one of my cluster Master server:
Create router:

```
 # oadm router ose-router --replicas=1 --credentials='/etc/origin/master/openshift-router.kubeconfig' --images='openshift-register.com.cn:5000/openshift3/ose-${component}:v3.4' --service-account=router
```

Create docker registry:

```
  # oadm registry --config=/etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig --service-account=registry --images='openshift-register.com.cn:5000/openshift3/ose-${component}:v3.4'
```

Router and registry are created successfully and we can see the docker-registry cluster-IP address is 172.30.182.170:

```
# oc get svc
NAME               CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                   AGE
docker-registry    172.30.182.170   <none>        5000/TCP                  22s
kubernetes         172.30.0.1       <none>        443/TCP,53/UDP,53/TCP     6d
ose-router         172.30.80.196    <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP,1936/TCP   1m
```

Query the iamge stems in namespace openshift, the Docker repo IP is 172.30.137.159:

```
# oc get is -n openshift
  NAME         DOCKER REPO                                TAGS                      
   jenkins      172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/jenkins      2,1                       
   mariadb      172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/mariadb      10.1                      
   mongodb      172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/mongodb      3.2,2.6,2.4               
   mysql        172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/mysql        5.7,5.6,5.5               
   nodejs       172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/nodejs       4,0.10                    
   perl         172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/perl         5.24,5.20,5.16            
   php          172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/php          5.5,7.0,5.6               
    postgresql   172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/postgresql   9.5,9.4,9.2               
    python       172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/python       3.4,3.3,2.7 + 
    more...
    redis        172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/redis        3.2                       
    ruby         172.30.137.159:5000/openshift/ruby         2.3,2.2,2.0
```

My concern and question are the docker repo IP address should be using my docker-registry service cluster IP by default, but why it generated a new IP address and I have no idea how/where to find this docker repo IP address? I'm really new openshift users, so if you can give any suggestion that would be appreciated.

```
[root@ocp-master01 ~]# oc get svc
NAME              CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                   AGE
docker-registry   172.30.182.170   <none>        5000/TCP                  49m
kubernetes        172.30.0.1       <none>        443/TCP,53/UDP,53/TCP     7d
ose-router        172.30.80.196    <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP,1936/TCP   50m
[root@ocp-master01 ~]# oc get svc -o yaml | grep IP
    clusterIP: 172.30.182.170
    sessionAffinity: ClientIP
    type: ClusterIP
    clusterIP: 172.30.0.1
    sessionAffinity: ClientIP
    type: ClusterIP
    clusterIP: 172.30.80.196
```

Comment: What happens if you try to restart your origin service on your nodes + master?

Comment: LOL!!! Debugged two days, never thought to restart the service, I knew there is some cache in the server, but don't know how to clean it. How stupid I am. Thanks, it's fixed!!!!!